# Exception caught by widgets library The following ArgumentError was thrown building HomePageScreen(dirty, state: _HomePageScreenState#3ae53):

Tags: android, flutter

Hi guys can you help me with this problem ? i just go around and doesn't get the right answer, thank you.

```
void _submit() {
  final form = formKey.currentState;
  if (form.validate()) {
    form.save();
    print(_username);
    print(_password);
    if (_username == "asdasd") {
      if (_password == "123") {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            this.context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => App()));
      } else {
        scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("login Failed, please re-type properly"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        )); // SnackBar
      }
    } else {
      scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("Login Failed, please re-type properly"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Error Message:**

> ```
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following ArgumentError was thrown building HomePageScreen(dirty, state: _HomePageScreenState#3ae53):
> Invalid argument(s)
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was: 
>   HomePageScreen file:///Users/andrehendrawan/Downloads/ican/lib/Screens/App.dart:20:5
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
> #0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:265:57)
> #1      _HomePageScreenState._greetings (package:ican/Screens/homePageScreen.dart:237:19)
> #2      _HomePageScreenState.build (package:ican/Screens/homePageScreen.dart:75:17)
> #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4334:27)
> #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Guys btw i just solve this problem , i just rebuilt my whole HomePageScreen and fill the statefull screen with same widget and i rerun it and the error gone , i don't know why buat it work